# Files from Adobe Bridge to Separate Folders

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, automation, script, adobe-bridge

Asking this again. I still haven't found a solution to this.

I have hundreds of images in a folder in bridge. [image]
I have tagged them alternatively by colour. The first bunch as Green, the second as Red the third as Green again and so forth. [image]

I want to copy each bunch in separate folders and rename the folder to the name of the first file in the folder. [image]

Is there a script that can automate this process?

Thank you!

Comment: As this is such a specific workflow, I'm pretty sure, no, there is no script for this. Have you tried coming up with a script yourself. Maybe in this case we could help you out in case you're stuck somewhere.

Comment: Since you already tagged the images by color, can't you just hide the other colors and select+move the visible files to a folder then repeat for other colors? Are the colors unique per folder?

Comment: Hi @mdomino, I don't have anything for now. Essentially, I think it's about Explorer somehow being able to read the Bridge color tags and copying them a bunch at a time.

Comment: Hey @Luciano, so they are all different batches. eg. the 1st greens have to go into the first folder, then reds into the 2nd, the following greens in the 3rd folder and so on... I have marked them alternatively. All greens don't have to go in the same folder.

Comment: maybe you should use keywords instead of the colored labels; you can only applly one label per image, but multiple keywords https://helpx.adobe.com/bridge/using/keywords-adobe-bridge.html#manage_keywords

Comment: @Luciano Sure! That won't be a problem. Is there a script to then move the groups of files into different subfolders?